# Login/Sign-Up via UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm attempting to create a login/sign up via alert pop up once the login or sign up button is clicked. I'm trying to implement this into Firebase 4. I have this so far but kinda stuck on how to implement Firebase. I have read their docs but I can't seem to get the `alertView` to work properly. Any suggestions?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class welcomeController: UIViewController {

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField in
        textField.placeholder = "Email"
        textField.keyboardType = .EmailAddress
    }

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField in
        textField.placeholder = "Password"
        textField.secureTextEntry = true
    }

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField in
        textField.placeholder = "Password Confirmation"
        textField.secureTextEntry = true
    }
    alertController.addAction(loginAction)
    alertController.addAction(forgotPasswordAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
}
```

Comment: I think it's missing the code to configure the 3 actions: loginAction, forgotPasswordAction and cancelAction.

Comment: It is and I'm kinda lost on how to hand an action. So if the login, sign up, forgot password, or cancel action is clicked.

Comment: see my answer ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer the following code. For demonstration of login and signup I have added action for login and signup. I have mentioned repeated code in login and signup action for better understanding. This code is just for your understanding.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Login/Signup", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Email"
        textField.keyboardType = .emailAddress
    }

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Password"
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }

    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Password Confirmation"
        textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }

    let loginAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: .default) { (_) in
        let emailField = alertController.textFields![0]
        let passwordField = alertController.textFields![1]
        let conformPasswordField = alertController.textFields![2]

        //Perform validation or whatever you do want with the text of textfield

        //Login With Firebase
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in
            // ...
        }

    }

    let signupAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Signup", style: .default) { (_) in
        let emailField = alertController.textFields![0]
        let passwordField = alertController.textFields![1]
        let conformPasswordField = alertController.textFields![2]

        //Perform validation or whatever you do want with the text of textfield

        //SigunUp With Firebase
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField.text!, password: passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in
            // ...
        }
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(loginAction)
    alertController.addAction(signupAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

To know more about firebase authentication and login/signup process with firebase please refer the below link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth

Comment: Thanks for all that, I'm getting this error though. Could you explain what this is. The login action is declared so I'm unsure to why it's displaying. Initialization of immutable value 'loginAction' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

Answer (score -1):

Handle the events in action handler, for example:

```
let loginAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SIGN UP", style: .default) { (action) in

    guard let textFields = alertController.textFields else { return } //show error

    let email       = textFields[0].text
    let password    = textFields[1].text
    let cPassword   = textFields[2].text

    print(email, password, cPassword)

}
```

Comment: How would this integrate with Firebase?

Comment: You just needed to call the API.